# I want to display all records from database in gridview and also if i search for particular record then i also performs 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to display all records from database in gridview when pageload and also i wanna search for particular record using textbox appear in my webform .

Means by default all records from the table will appear in gridview using sqldatasource and i also wanna search for a particular record by enter ID in text box ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net-2.0/asp.net-2.0-gridview-filtering.html

Google is your friend...